# will WinRT components work in windows 7

Tags: windows, windows-7, windows-runtime

I've read that windows has new api from windows 8 and it's called WinRT, I intend to use it But I'm worried about windows 7.

### My Goal

I'm planning to build a new programming language and use it but in order for it to be usable it must have Gui Programming, I didn't want to wrap calls to C libraries and fortunately I can avoid it in linux and Mac OS X by building a new display server for the propose of the new language(and there are open source projects to help me here).

But windows is closed source and so When I build the display server I have to wrap calls to its api.

I want to use the WinRT as it's new so it's mostly much easier but I'm worried that it won't work in windows 7.

### Question

So my question is : will WinRT work under windows 7 provided I don't care about metro style apps for now ? if not directly is there a way to make it work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short: NO, WinRT will never run on Windows 7. It's a different (new) API, for more details, read this reply in a similar thread: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11177613/318501.

It's also very important to note that Windows 7 (with SP1) is already [out of mainstream support](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/lifecycle), meaning that you don't have to expect Microsoft from adding it in a future patch for consumers.

Comment: the second link points to my question :3, about windows 7 I'm worried about it mainly because I might work with some people how don't have windows 10 or 8, anyway your answer is correct, I guess I'll tell them to upgrade

Comment: If they hurry, they'll get a free upgrade (1st year offer only). Updated the link to Microsoft's lifecycle page.

Comment: well yes but they need some good hardware I think, one of my friends has an old toshiba and it barely runs windows 7.

Comment: The Windows Runtime isn't *"new"* by any stretch. It's just a slimmed down version of COM. There's no technical reason why a WinRT component cannot be made to run on Windows 7.