# Why can C++/WinRT run on Windows 7 now?

Tags: windows-7, c++-winrt

"according to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32945709/will-winrt-components-work-in-windows-7),c++/winrt doesn't support win7, because win7 got no winrt; but this [project](https://github.com/kennykerr/win7) can run on win7, what happendd? win7 got winrt? winrt deployed to win7?"

need to known why c++/winrt can run on win7 now, thanks

Comment: The Windows Runtime needs very little OS support, and to my knowledge, C++/WinRT had always been able to produce binaries that execute on Windows 7. It's just not a message you want folks hear when your objective is to drop support for shipped versions of Windows as quickly as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"WinRT" as referenced in the first post you linked is a common short-hand for "Windows Runtime". There are no "Windows Runtime" style APIs supported on Windows 7. Windows 8 or later is required to find support for any "Windows Runtime" API.

> In the early days of Windows 8, the "Windows on ARM" OS was called "Windows RT" which people sometimes shortened to "WinRT" which just added to the confusion.

"C++/WinRT language projections" are a way to consume "Windows Runtime" APIs, and can also be used for COM APIs. Kenny's project demonstrates how you can use C++/WinRT in a binary that runs on Windows 10 and down-level on Windows 7. The "Windows Runtime" APIs are still not there. It's just using COM only on Windows 7.